# Unreal Enginge Toggle / Hold to sprint problem

Tags: game-physics, physics, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am new to unreal engine and game-making overall. I need help with this issue I can't seem to fix it myself. How do I make it so that I hold shift to sprint instead of shift toggling sprint?

[image: Image of the movement blueprint]

I've tried experimenting but I only end up with errors. Can't seem to find a solution by googling.

Comment: Can you please add more details of what you tried and what went wrong? Also, could you please reduce the tag-spamming? This question is unrelated to `physics`. Just add the tags for the engine and the language you are using (in this case [`unreal-blueprint`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-blueprint)).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use both the `Pressed` and `Released` events: when shift is `pressed`, set the `Running` flag to true and update the speed to reflect that the player is running, and when the shift key is `Released` just set it to false (and lower the player speed accordingly)